# Creating an game menu in OpenGL tutorials

Tags: opengl, menu, 3dsmax

I'm creating a 3D game in OpenGL.
The main thing at the moment I want to know is how can I create a menu?
e.g. Main menu, in game pause menu, Options and even the gamer HUD to display HP etc.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to where I can get tutorials on this?

Also if anyone can give hint on loading 3D models with texture and animation into OpenGL that would be very much appreciated. Most of the models and animation is done in Autodesk 3DS Max, textures in PS CS6.

Comment: Try to avoid asking more than one question in a SO question. Also, asking for references/books is frowned upon if it is something that can be searched on your own. Try looking at the [OpenGL tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/opengl/info) for some help as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following link which will show you complete walkthrough for designing a tetris game in opengl. Read it till end and then go your own way:-

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30775/TetroGL-An-OpenGL-Game-Tutorial-in-C-for-Win32-pla